# Javascript: Multiplying dynamically sized array values simultaneously

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a dynamically sized array that looks something like this:

```
var myArray = [0.10,0.12,0.08,0.08];
```

The array can have more or less values than above.

The aim here is to plug them into the following formula:

```
var iFormula = 1 - ((1 - value1)*(1 - value2)*(1 - value3)* ... (1 - valuen))
```

I tried the following for loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < myArray .length; i++) {

    iResult = iResult * (1 - myArray[i])
};
```

Then subtracted iResult from 1 but as you can imagine, doing the above for loop is not the same as calculating iFormula. For example, using the array at the top of my question, if I combine the two 0.08 values together to make the following array:

```
var myArray = [0.10,0.12,0.16];
```

The two following equations use the same effective numbers but produce two different results:

```
var iResult_1 = 1 - ((1 - 0.10)*(1 - 0.12)*(1 - 0.08)*(1 - 0.08)); // 0.3297
var iResult_2 = 1 - ((1 - 0.10)*(1 - 0.12)*(1 - 0.16));            // 0.3347
```

As the array is dynamically sized, I don't know how many values will be in the array when it reaches a certain part of my code. Therefore, I can't hardcode the formula to be something like:

```
var iFormula = 1 - ((1 - myArray[0])*(1 - myArray[1])*(1 - myArray[2])
```

Any ideas how I can construct this? Is there a much better way of doing this sort of thing?

Comment: No, I can't imagine. The `for` loop should work perfectly. Did you initialize `iResult` to `1` before the loop?

Comment: Have you forgotten high school algebra? `(1 - x) * (1 - x)` is not equal to `(1 - 2x)`. It's equal to `(1 - 2x + x^2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your algorithm based on a `for` loop is OK.

I'm just wondering how you expect `iResult_1` and `iResult_2` to be equal. Here is my absurd demonstration:

```
(1 - 1) !== (1 - 0.5) * (1 - 0.5)
// 0 !== 0.25
```

About the way to do this computation in a nicer way, here is my suggestion based on [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2FReduce):

```js
function calculate(arr) {
    return 1 - arr.reduce(function(res, cur) {
            return res * (1 - cur);
        }, 1);
}

document.write(calculate([0.10, 0.12, 0.08, 0.08]));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and tip on the reduce function, very handy!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
iResult =1;
for(var i = 0; i < myArray .length; i++) {

    iResult = iResult * (1 - myArray[i])
};
iResult = 1 - iResult ;
```

Comment: Add some explanation to your answer please.

Comment: He just has to initialize the value of iresult befor loop!

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the array elements with `myArray[i]`. And make sure you initialize `iResult` properly before the loop.

```js
var myArray = [0.10,0.12,0.08,0.08];
var value1 = myArray[0],
    value2 = myArray[1],
    value3 = myArray[2],
    value4 = myArray[3];

var iFormula = 1 - ((1 - value1)*(1 - value2)*(1 - value3)* (1 - value4));
document.getElementById('iFormula').innerHTML = iFormula;

var iResult = 1;
for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {

    iResult = iResult * (1 - myArray[i])
};
iResult = 1 - iResult;
document.getElementById('iResult').innerHTML = iResult;
```

```html
<div>iFormula = <span id="iFormula"></span></div>
<div>iResult = <span id="iResult"></span></div>
```